# D3: Nothing getting rendered in enter selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and I am trying to create a basic bar chart. Here is my complete code

```
names = [
    {'name': 'Locke', value: 4},
    {'name': 'Reyes', value: 8},
    {'name': 'Ford', value: 15},
    {'name': 'Jarrah', value: 16},
    {'name': 'Shephard', value: 23},
    {'name': 'Kwon', value: 42}
]

var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

 width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

 x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

 chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width)


update  = function(obj){
    x.domain([0, d3.max(obj, function(d){ return d.value;})]);
    chart.attr("height", barHeight * obj.length);

    bar = chart.selectAll("g")
        .data(obj, function(d){return d.name})

    bar.append("rect")
        .attr("height", barHeight - 1)
        .attr('width', '0px')
        .transition().delay(200).duration(3000)
        .attr("width", function(d){ console.log('updating'); return x(d.value);})

    bar.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
        .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

    bar.enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

    bar.exit()
        .remove();
}

update(names);
```

I am writing 'enter' selection at the end, so that I don't have to duplicate same for enter and update selection. But currently nothing is getting rendered and also there is no error in the console. Can someone explain me why this is happening, and what should be the code structure for **enter, update and exit** selection?

Comment: Post you complete code

Comment: @ozil updated the code

Comment: [Is this what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/21t4vvo2/)

Comment: @ozil it's only showing one bar line. Also, will it work for update and exit selection?

Comment: @ozil I observed that u removed key mapping from inside '.data()'. This way it will always remove the last element in array during exit selection

Comment: You should only append elements on the enter selection, not the update selection.